# How can I access the method of one thread from another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

The app I currently developing should create the bunch of threads, each containing some data collection and creating the bunch of threads itself. These threads (third layer) should receive some data and send it to the collection in their parent thread, which then will send this data further.

My problem here is I can't find a way to access either collection itself or the method made to modify it from another thread. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! What have you tried already?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe, searching StackOverflow =)
Seriously now, the problem is, I can't find something I should try, because I can't find anything that gives desired result.
I was thinking about parent-child thread relations, but couldn't find something that could help me in that. I can't use global collections either. So... That's the deal.

Comment: One 'classic' method would be by signaling a producer-consumer queue instance from the parent class to the child classes in their constructors.  The children post the data objects to the queue and the parent waits on the queue and updates/maintains the collection. If the parent wants to send the collection on, if can push it's collection to another P-C queue and create anothr collection instance for new data.

Comment: You don't access collections, you share them between threads

Answer (score 2):

Your problem statement is very vague, so i can only point to some resources that might or might not help you:

- [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/) is a very good book on concurrency and multi-threading in Java
- Maybe the [Fork/Join framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) can help you?
- If you are using Spring already, you might want to check out [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/).

Answer (score 1):

If you simply wish to share a collection between the *parent thread* and the *child threads* you can declare a variable and pass it to the child thread. So, how do you pass it to the child thread? Well, you either create a `Runnable` or some other executable piece that holds your object like in the example below (the `Runnable` can be executed in another thread).

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final Queue<String> sharedQueue;

    public MyRunnable(Queue<String> sharedQueue) {
        this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
    }

    public void run() {
        // do stuff with sharedQueue here
    }
}
```

And to start a thread:

```
final Queue<String> q = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
new Thread(new MyRunnable(q)).start();
```

The other alternative is to use anonymous inner classes (or lambdas) like in the example below that simply starts a bunch of futures and shares the data to the `Queue` (which likely is a good candidate for sharing data):

```
// Shared data
final Queue<String> q = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

// Declare some threads (you can skip this part and instead use the ForkJoinPool)
// which is the default thread pool for CompletableFuture
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

// Create tasks, complete all of them
CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.allOf(
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> q.offer(Thread.currentThread().getName()), executorService),
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> q.offer(Thread.currentThread().getName()), executorService),
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> q.offer(Thread.currentThread().getName()), executorService),
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> q.offer(Thread.currentThread().getName()), executorService),
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> q.offer(Thread.currentThread().getName()), executorService)
);

// Wait for the threads to complete
future.get();

// Print the result
q.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it right, give the 2nd layer thread as parameter when constructing the 3th layer threads. the 3th layer threads can then access the collections from the second layer threads directly, or probably better, call a receiveData(...) method of the second layer thread.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at `ExecutorService` and `Callable`. It doesn't do what you **ask** for because it doesn't put the result in collections but it might just be what you **need**.

Here's an example.

```
package whatever;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Example
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Future<String> result = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
            public String call() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(20);
                return "some data";
            }
        }
        );
        String value = result.get();
        System.out.println("The thread returned:" + value);
    }
}
```

The call `executor.submit` starts a thread and returns a `Future`. When the thread returns, it puts the value in the `Future` and the parent thread can retrieve it, whenever its ready, by calling `get`. There are other methods you can use to verify that the thread has completed.

It wasn't clear from your question if that would suffice but since it's rather simple to implement, you may want to consider using it if it meets your requirements.